# VBA to collapse/expand all rows in a PivotTable which includes a Filter

Tags: excel, vba

**Excel:**

```
   |      A       |       B       |       C       |     D    |
---|--------------|---------------|---------------|----------|---
1  |    Channel   |    Category   |    Product    |   Sales  |
---|--------------|---------------|---------------|----------|---
2  |    Online    |    Apparel    |   Product A   |    500   |
3  |    Online    |    Apparel    |   Product A   |    400   |
4  |    Retail    |    Shoes      |   Product A   |    600   |
5  |    Retail    |    Apparel    |   Product B   |    300   |
6  |    Retail    |    Beauty     |   Product C   |    100   |
7  |    Online    |    Shoes      |   Product C   |    200   |
8  |    Retail    |    Apparel    |   Product D   |    450   |
9  |    Retail    |    Beauty     |   Product D   |    700   |
10 |    Online    |    Beauty     |   Product D   |    250   |
11 |              |               |               |          |
```

**PivotTable:**

[image]

---

On the above PivotTable I want to run a VBA to expand/collapse all the rows. 
I was able to do this with this code:

```
Sub PivotTable_Collapse()
Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(1).ShowDetail = True
End Sub
```

However, after I implemented the `filter Channel` into the PivotTable the VBA does not expand/collapse the rows anymore.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Most likely as 'Channel' will now have become the PivotField with index 1. Try referencing the field explicitly instead, i.e. `PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Category").ShowDetail = True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the solution is:

```
Sub PivotTable_Collapse()
Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(2).ShowDetail = True
End Sub
```